# Drag-drop: How to draw a "ghost" control that represents data being dragged?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, drag-and-drop

I have searched a lot and the nearest thing I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240603/c-drag-and-drop-show-the-dragged-item-while-dragging). The question is exactly about what I want to code, but there's only one vague answer. Searched code.google.com for GiveFeedback implementations, but none about what I want. Any idea, please?

Comment: Add the info about the platfrom or framework that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is C# / Windows Forms, if you use the built-in API for drag & drop, then you get a "dragging" mouse cursor for free. That is really the easiest solution.