# How can I use an Image List to draw C# dragging outside of my own windows

Tags: c#, windows, drag-and-drop, imagelist

I am using C#'s inbuilt drag and drop via Control.DoDragDrop().  I use an Image List and ImageList_DragMove and friends to move a semi-transparent image around, tracking with the mouse.  (See my reply in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240603/c-drag-and-drop-show-the-dragged-item-while-dragging/3665135#3665135) for more information).  How can I make the ImageList track the mouse when it is *outside* my windows?  I only receive mouse position messages in OnDragOver(), and only when the mouse is over one of my Windows.  The drag is going to another instance of my application, and I would like the ImageList to go the whole way, including over the desktop.  I guess the basic problem is that DoDragDrop runs its own little message loop.

Windows Explorer gets this done so I know it is possible.  I suppose I could start a thread to keep track of the mouse or write my own drag/drop message loop, but I am hoping for an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot draw outside your own windows.  The way to do this is by changing the mouse cursor.  That's what the GiveFeedback event is available, set e.UseDefaultCursors to false and set the Cursor.Current.

Just to give you an idea what this looks like, here's a sample form that drags visible text.  Alter it to draw the bitmap the way you want it, from your ImageList for example.  Beware that Bitmap.GetHicon() does not create great icons, the color mapping is poor.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.GiveFeedback += Form1_GiveFeedback;
    }

    void Form1_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e) {
        string txt = "Dragging text";
        SizeF sz;
        using (var gr = this.CreateGraphics()) {
            sz = gr.MeasureString(txt, this.Font);
        }
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap((int)sz.Width, (int)sz.Height)) {
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                gr.Clear(Color.White);
                gr.DrawString(txt, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
            }
            bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
            e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
            IntPtr hIcon = bmp.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(hIcon);
            DestroyIcon(hIcon);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
        this.DoDragDrop("example", DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);

}
```

Comment: You _can_ draw outside your own windows; Image List can do this.  However you are right that GiveFeedback is the answer to my question, because I can call ImageList_DragMove() from within it.  I guess I never considered it because its description goes on so much about mouse cursors.  Your suggestion of using a custom icon is interesting, but I won't pursue it because you say Bitmap.GetHIcon has problems with colour, and anyway the Image List gives the nice transparent effect I like.

Comment: The _trouble_ with using image lists is that it is difficult to ensure that the drag source removes the image before any processing occurs at the target.  If you fail to do this then when the drag image _is_ removed it may mess up the screen because it restores the screen's state as it was when the image was drawn.  A custom mouse cursor would not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a special form and drag it instead of using an ImageList.  We have done this in our products (for example, XtraGrid) to allow the end-user arrange columns.

Comment: While this is an interesting idea, it does not address how to get mouse feedback while the mouse pointer is over other windows, and when calling DoDragDrop().  Perhaps DevExpress implements their own drag/drop message loop.

Comment: No, we did not implement our own message loop.  When you drag a window, the mouse cursor is always above your window and thus you may override its OnMouseMove method to move the drag window...