# How can i replace cursor with bitmap in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am develeoping a magnifier on Mouse move control application in c#.net . I need to replace the cursor with the magnifier control(magnifier control is a picturebox). So is there anyway to accomplish this .

Comment: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors

Comment: Nice ... I am going to implement my concept with this one ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example code below shows how to set a Cursor on windows form. The same approach can be used to set a Cursor for a Control too.

```
public class Form_With_A_Cursor_Example {
    public void Shows_A_Form_With_A_Cursor_Loaded_From_A_pictureBox() {         
        Form frm = new Form();
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox() { Image = Image.FromFile( @"C:\Users\xxx\Pictures\someImage.bmp" ) };

        frm.Cursor = new Cursor( ( (Bitmap)pb.Image ).GetHicon() );

        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First add bitmap to your project resources:
Project->projectnameProperties->Add exiting file (from menu next to "Add Resource") add your BMP

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(projectname.Properties.Resources.yourCursorName);
b.MakeTransparent(b.GetPixel(0,0));
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
IntPtr ptr = b.GetHicon();
Cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(ptr);
```

Where "projectname" is the name of your project.